# JavaScript: Numerical Grade to Letter Grade

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

**1.** Create a function toLetterGrade that takes an array of percentages and returns an array of corresponding grade letters. For example:

`toLetterGrade([90,80,55,85]); //returns ["A","A-","C","A"]`

**2.** Create a function toGradePoints that takes an array of letter grades and returns a corresponding array of grades points. For example:

`toGradePoints(["A","A-","C","A"]); //returns [4.0,3.7,2.0,4.0]`

**3.** Create a function GPA that takes an array of percentages and returns the corresponding grade point average.

I'm trying to do number 1, and this is the code I have so far, but it only gives me the letter grade for the last number in the array. What am I doing wrong?

```
var arr

function toLetterGrade(arr) {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] >= 85) {
            textG = "A";
        } else if (arr[i] >= 80) {
            textG = "A-";
        } else if (arr[i] >= 75) {
            textG = "B+";
        } else if (arr[i] >= 70) {
            textG = "B";
        } else if (arr[i] >= 65) {
            textG = "B-";
        } else if (arr[i] >= 60) {
            textG = "C+";
        } else if (arr[i] >= 55) {
            textG = "C";
        } else if (arr[i] >= 50) {
            textG = "D";
        } else {
            textG = "F";
        }
    }
    return textG;
}

document.write(toLetterGrade([90, 80, 70]))
```

Output is B.

Comment: please add where do you get the numbers for the second question.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your variable with every cycle of the loop, that's why you are getting only one - the last grade.

I suggest you to use an empty array variable to store results inside.

With every loop you will assign new grade to the `textG` variable and then push it into the `result` array. The `textG` variable gets reseted with every loop `textG = ''` so  there's no risk to duplicate/overwrite results.

After all cycles of the `for` loop, the `result` array is returned.

```js
function toLetterGrade(arr) {
  var textG = '';
  var result = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    textG = '';
    if (arr[i] >= 85) {
      textG = "A";
    } else if (arr[i] >= 80) {
      textG = "A-";
    } else if (arr[i] >= 75) {
      textG = "B+";
    } else if (arr[i] >= 70) {
      textG = "B";
    } else if (arr[i] >= 65) {
      textG = "B-";
    } else if (arr[i] >= 60) {
      textG = "C+";
    } else if (arr[i] >= 55) {
      textG = "C";
    } else if (arr[i] >= 50) {
      textG = "D";
    } else {
      textG = "F";
    }
    result.push(textG);
  }
  return result;
}

document.write(toLetterGrade([90, 80, 70]))
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, you could use an object and iterate the keys for the wanted grade.

```js
function getGrade(p) {
    var grade = 'F';
    Object.keys(grades).some(function (k) {
        if (p >= grades[k]) {
            grade = k;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return grade
}

var grades = { A: 85, 'A-': 80, B: 70, 'B-': 65, 'C+': 60, C: 55, D: 50, F: '' }

console.log([90, 80, 55, 85].map(getGrade));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @dv, please add why.

Comment: Someone just got mad and dv every entry. By the way, it's kinda pointless to use such modern solutions here like `Object.keys` since OP is not even able to make right conditions.

Comment: even if op is actually not able to get the idea, i think it is neccessary to write a solution with some advanced functions. the serial dv may have an agenda, which is hidden and therefore only destructive.

Comment: Agreed. I've upvoted your answer, `-1` doesn't look really good. (:

Comment: @Kinduser: Object.keys() has been standard and shipping for over 5 years...

Comment: @dandavis 5 years?! That's a lot. But I'm in the bussiness since one year :(

Comment: instead of hard-coding grade 'F' you can just get last grade:

`let grade = Object.values(grades)[Object.keys(grades).length]`

Comment: @ДаниилПронин, this relies on a sorted object.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the grade to a variable and then overwriting it with each iteration.

try textG.push('A') instead

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your return value with each iteration.

Try creating an array, and adding the solution onto the array.

`var solutionArr = [];`

`solutionArr.push("A");`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zpspp7p/)

Answer (score 0):

I make this simple code to check letter grade from a numerical

```
const letterGrade = (n) => {
  let resultGrade = "";
  if (n >= 90) {
    resultGrade = "A";
  } else if (n >= 80 || n > 89) {
    resultGrade = "B";
  } else if (n >= 70 || n > 79) {
    resultGrade = "C";
  } else if (n >= 60 || n > 69) {
    resultGrade = "D";
  } else if (n < 59) {
    resultGrade = "E";
  } else {
    alert("Input your grade first");
  }
  return `Your grade is ${resultGrade}`;
};

console.log(letterGrade(75));
```